# Counting Files with a Spatial Reference using Python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy

I need to display a *list* of feature classes with an unknown spatial reference, and the *number* of feature classes with a spatial reference. I think I have the first part right, but having troubles with the second part. I've been playing around with the `len()` and `count()` but those always result in an error. The following is part of my code:

```
for fC in fCList:
     desc = arcpy.Describe(fC)
     spatialRef = desc.spatialReference
     if spatialRef.Name == 'Unknown': # List of feature classes that are unknown
        print "\n" + fC, ("has an 'Unknown' spatial reference\n")
     else: # Number of feature classes that have a spatial reference
        print ("Total number of feature classes with a spatial reference:"), count(fC)
```

Comment: This seems like a pure Python question... have you gone through the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: The gist of the issue here is that you aren't keeping a persistent variable to count feature classes with/without a spatial reference. Majgis's solution below is a very pythonic method for doing so, but you could just as easily (or perhaps more easily; list comprenhensions give me a headache) use your else clause to increment a variable counting fc's with a spatial reference and then subtract it from the length of the fCList when your loop completes.

Comment: @Nathanus Thanks for your help! I shall try it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
unknowns = [fc for fc in fCList if arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.Name == "Unknown"]

knownCount = len(fCList) - len(unknowns)

print "Known Total:", knownCount
print "Unknowns:\n   ", "\n    ".join(unknowns)
```

If you are unsure how the unknowns list is created, see [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could use `for`/`if` statements in lists. Sorry, I'm new to Python. Thanks for your help @majgis!

Comment: List comprehensions are handy, but be careful, they are hard to read and debug if they are too complex.  Also, realize we're storing a list in memory, which is overkill for your simple example, but more versatile for a structured approach (pass this list to a series of functions if you decide to take additional steps).